# Elasticsearch | update_by_query | Maintain uniqueness in a multi-value field

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a field `field_keyword` in my elasticsearch index of type array, I am trying to append the `field_keyword` field with new values, but I would like to avoid duplicate values getting added to the list.

For Eg:

If I pass the below request twice,

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "field": "Invoice Number"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "locale": "US"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
 "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.field_keyword.add(params.new_field_keyword);",
    "params": {
      "new_field_keyword": "Invois #"
    }
  }
}
```

The value `"Invois #"` gets added twice,

```
"field_keyword": [      "TAX INVOICE NO. :",
                        "Invois #",
                        "Invois #"]
```

How to avoid the element getting added twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to avoid the element getting added twice.

Only Add if the value doesn't exist.

**E.g :**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "term": {
        "field": "Invoice Number"
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "locale": "US"
      }
    }
  ]
}
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "if(!ctx._source.field_keyword.contains(params.new_field_keyword)){ctx._source.field_keyword.add(params.new_field_keyword)}",
    "params": {
      "new_field_keyword": "Invois #"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also do the same with a pipeline with a set processor and a if